Why didn't Rosalind Franklin's X-Ray crystallography photograph contain any histones, methyl groups, or transcription factors?
When DNA is condensing, it wraps around histones, where it can also be methylated with the addition of a methyl group. On top of this, DNA has transcription factors which determine what can be transcribed into RNA.
I understand that Rosalind Franklin had pure DNA from Signer which she converted to a paracrystalline form by raising the humidity of the specimen. How was it that none of these structures that we know DNA attaches to or are attached to DNA didn't show up in photo 51?

That's actually a great question, and it makes a lot of sense to wonder why we don't see histones, methyl groups, or transcription factors in Rosalind Franklin's famous Photo 51. The key to understanding this lies in the context of the experiment and the type of DNA Franklin was studying.


When Franklin took the X-ray diffraction image that became Photo 51, she was working with highly purified DNA fibers, not DNA from inside a living cell. This purified DNA had been isolated by the Swiss scientist Rudolf Signer and was stripped of any proteins, histones, or other cellular components like transcription factors. The DNA was essentially "naked" and free from the structures it normally associates with inside the nucleus.
Another important point is that X-ray diffraction only reveals the overall repeating structure of molecules, especially those that form highly ordered, crystalline or paracrystalline patterns. In Franklin's case, she hydrated the DNA just enough to form a paracrystalline structure, where the molecules were aligned in a regular, repeating pattern. The repeating nature of DNA's helical structure is what generated the characteristic "X" shape in Photo 51, which provided critical information about the double helix.
Histones, transcription factors, or even methyl groups would not form such regular, repeating patterns. They are more varied in size and shape, and they don't contribute to a uniform diffraction pattern like the helical backbone of DNA does. Furthermore, their presence would have been too sparse or irregular to significantly affect the X-ray diffraction image. In the purified conditions Franklin was working with, these additional elements weren't present to interfere with the image, which is why they didn't show up.
So, the reason why you don't see those other components in Photo 51 is simply because Franklin was working with DNA in a highly purified, idealized form, and the X-ray diffraction method specifically highlighted the repeating, regular structure of the DNA itself.

Chemist here. I would further note that when DNA is doing what it is best known for (replicating) it isn't wrapped around histones. It is floating free, where the polymerase can run along the chain and replicate. Histones are not required for the base pairing and would get in the way during replication. The bases and the sugar-phosphate backbone are primary structure; the base pairing is secondary structure, and the coiling around histones is tertiary structure.

Note that the use of generative LLMs is banned on SE and this answer, as did others from your hand, are suspected of being AI generated. Please refrain from using ChatGTP (yup 'GTP', biologist here) or other generative AI tools in the future, or the mod team may have to undertake action.

@AliceD I went to the comments as my AI sense tingled around the second sentence already.

@htmlcoderexe- thanks for the comment, and if that sixth sense tickles again, please also hit that 'flag' button.

@AliceD - ChatGTP for a DNA answer. Love it!

@anongoodnurse, why thank you <3
